# setAnimationTransition:forView:cache: objects are "glitching" during transition

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft in my application and it displays a new view with a text field and two buttons. On the iPhone, as it's loading the view, the text field will be scrunched up and the text on the buttons off-center until the view has loaded, then after a very small delay, the text field and buttons' centerings will correct themselves. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer while searching through some topics on StackOverflow. For anyone who is interested, it was the ORDER of method calls that made the difference.

Original code:

1. Set up the transition
2. removeFromSuperview view1
3. addSubview view2
4. commitAnimations

No my drawing glitches when changed to:

1. removeFromSuperview view1
2. addSubview view2
3. set up the transition
4. commitAnimations